# why should conditioning on a random variable subtract information from it?

Tags: statistics, fisher-information, sufficient-statistics

The defintion of a sufficient statistic is as follows:

> A statistic $t = T(X)$ is sufficient for underlying parameter $θ$ precisely if the conditional probability distribution of the data $X$, given the statistic $t = T(X)$, does not depend on the parameter $θ$

That is data $X$ had some information about $\theta$, say $I(\theta;X)$ then this information get subtracted from $X$ if i condition on the random variable $T(X)$.

I do not understand why condtioning on a random variable should 'subtract information' from $X$

What i mean is that while i am comfortable thinking in the following manner:

> if $X=Y+Z$ where $Z$ contains no information about $\theta$ then
> subtracting $Y$ from $X$ subtracts information from $X$ about
> $\theta$.

But, the idea that conditioning *can* subtract information is a little unsettling at best.
So, is there any mathematical justification for why conditioning on a random variable *can* subtract information from that random variable?

Comment: The infomation is still there , but we can possibly not recover it from the conditioned random variable. "Subtracting information" is a strange description of what is going on.

Comment: @Peter Can it be shown mathematically that the information is still there?